# Simple way to store React state between components

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-redux

I have a React app that has multiple tabs. When the user goes to the "Data" tab it will fetch data from an API call and set the data in a React state. However, if the user goes from "Data" tab to "Home" tab then back to "Data" tab it will have to fetch the data again from API call because data in state has disappeared.

Psuedocode of desired functionality:

```
const OutputTab: React.FC<PageProps> = ({ match, pageName }) => {
  const [outputData, setOutputData] = useState<outputsInterface[]>([]);

  useIonViewWillEnter(() => {
    if (!outputData) {
      fetchOutputs();
    }
  });

  const fetchOutputs = () => {
    let response = fetch("....");
    setOutputData(response.json);
  };
};
```

What is the simplest way to store the state data? Desired functionality is when user comes back to the tab we can simply check if data already exists rather than making another API call to refetch.

I thought of possible solutions to use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` but I'd prefer to store the data in memory rather than storage. Do I need something like Redux to accomplish this?

Comment: Redux is highly recommended and once you set it up it will be really easy to manage state. Another way would be to pass the state as props, but this can get very tedious very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

full solution with video examples here with source code in codesandbox

- https://youtu.be/DiCzp5kIcP4
- https://dev.to/aaronksaunders/two-ways-to-manage-state-in-react-js-5dkb

Using Context API

```
import React from "react";

// create the context
export const Context = React.createContext();

// create the context provider, we are using use state to ensure that
// we get reactive values from the context...
export const TheProvider = ({ children }) => {
  // the reactive values
  const [sharedValue, setSharedValue] = React.useState({
    value: "initial",
    changedBy: "Admin"
  });

  // the store object
  let state = {
    sharedValue,
    setSharedValue
  };

  // wrap the application in the provider with the initialized context
  return <Context.Provider value={state}>{children}</Context.Provider>;
};

export default Context;
```

Using Reducer with useReducer

```
  const reducer = (state: IState, action: ActionType): IState => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "update":
        return { ...state, ...action.payload };
      case "clear":
        return { ...state, ...action.payload, value: "" };
      default:
        throw new Error();
    }
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
```

Comment: You are a legend. I was actually looking on your blog and Github before posting but I didn't come across this. Your code has helped me many times in the past. Thank you!

Comment: trying to be more organized with my content all content is on dev.to and videos are on youtube channel with links to source code and blog post if there is one - https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMCcqbJpyL3LAv3PJeYz2bg